# proving a limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $h:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ a function and $\alpha\in\mathbb R\backslash\{0\}$.

I want to proove that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(x)}{x}=c$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(\alpha x)}{x}=\alpha c$.

I've tried to define $\xi(x):=\frac{h(x)}{x}$ and so $\xi(\alpha x)=\frac{h(\alpha x)}{\alpha x}$ what is equivalent to $\alpha\cdot \xi(\alpha x)=\frac{h(\alpha x)}{x}$.

So it's $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(\alpha x)}{x}=\alpha\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\xi(\alpha x)$.

But now I am stuck. Anybody could help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly is $c$? Can $c$ be anything?

Comment: Well, you got it. You just have to see that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \xi(\alpha x)= \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \xi(y)=c$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(x)}{x}=c$. Then $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(\alpha x)}{x}=\alpha\lim_{x\to0}\frac{h(\alpha x)}{\alpha x}=\alpha\lim_{u\to0}\frac{h(u)}{u}=\alpha c.$$ Note the substitution $u=\alpha x$.

Comment: @user31035: If you don't see why that substitution works, try to prove it, using the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of limits.

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: Let $f:X\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$,$g:f(X)\to \mathbb{R}$ be two functions such as that $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=y_0\in f(X)$$ If $f(x)\neq y_0$ near $x_0$ (but not necessarily at $x_0$) and $$\lim_{y\to y_0}g(y)=\ell$$ then, 
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}(g\circ f)(x)=\ell$$

Can you apply it in this case? What functions will be your $f,g$ and what point will be your $x_0$?